# Winforms hosting WPF control and native wpf window look different

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

When i display WPF GUI in native wpf window it looks like this

[image]

But when i host it in Winfowms, it looks like this

[image: winfowms host]

Wpf View code

```
        <StackPanel>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
               <TextBlock x:Name="tb1">Histogram intervals:</TextBlock>
               <TextBox Width="100"></TextBox>
           </StackPanel>
           <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock x:Name="tb2" Width="105">Mistie threshold, m:</TextBlock>
              <TextBox Width="100" ></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

Also, as you can see, there are some font render difference. How can i solve these problems?
Updated:
The problem is that wpf native and wpf hosted inside Winforms has different font. So  tb1 width changes in winforms, because its not hard coded as tb2, and depends on text render size.

Comment: It might be useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Will add example soon, but i think its not necessary for font/control render.

Comment: It's hard to say what is important, not knowing which `LayoutPanel` you use. Maybe it's not the font at all

Comment: Added an example, there are different fonts in Winforms and Wpf

Answer (score 2):

Bug happens because winforms set other font for all text in wpf control
I solved this, by adding

```
 FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="12"
```

to my Usercontrol, which hosted by winforms.

These attributes force winform to use that fonts.

Comment: Glad you find a solution. Anyway if you use a `Grid` instead of `Stackpanel` inside `Stackpanel` the textboxes would stay aligned. Imagine you want to change the font(size) some day. You would have to change the whole layout again.

Comment: I dont like to work with grid, because annoying Grid.Row Grid.Column attributes. It woulb be usefull if controls set to cells automaticaly.
For example take grid with 2 rows and 2 columns.
 First control in grid.Childs would be Row=0 Column 0. Second would be Row=0,Column1. Etc.. Is that possible?
For case you described i using  {Binding Path = Width, ElementName = tb1}

Comment: you could also use a `ItemsControl` if you want something more generic